# Selecting Data Across Multiple Tables in MySQL

Tags: drupal, mysql

Ok, I'm trying to end up with a view that returns some fields from a Drupal instance running on MySQL. The problem is this information is spread out over three tables:

table 1 (keyword_search_table): contains the following fields:

id, keyword, dst
example data:
1, 'chicken', 'aboutus/fred'
2, 'boxes', 'services/patching_stuff'

table 2 (url_alias): contains the following fields:

pid, src, dst
example data:
45, 'node/22','aboustus/fred'
46, 'node/36','patching_stuff'

table 3 (node_revisions): contains the following fields:

nid, title, teaser
example data:

22, 'About Fred - Our President', 'Fred is a great guy and has been pres for 4 years...'
36, 'Patching Your Deck', 'Patching your deck should be done using barbed wire..."

I'm trying to end up with this:

keyword, destination_url, title, teaser_text

example output based on data above:

1. chicken, aboutus/fred, About Fred - Our President, Fred is a great guy and has been pres for 4 years...
2. Boxes, services/patching_stuff, Patching Your Deck, Patching your deck should be done using barbed wire...

Im guessing I need to do some inner outer and left joins...I'm bad at writing this stuff. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get that data because url_alias doesn't contain nid only pid. JOIN can be made on similiar fields in different tables. for example, I will select data from keyword_search_table and node_revisions.title.

```
SELECT keyword_search_table.nid, keyword_search_table.keyword, node_revisions.title, node_revisions.teaser FROM keyword_search_table INNER JOIN ON keyword_search_table.nid = node_revisions.nid;
```

if url_alias having nid (or You can be sure that nid=pid) your query should look something like that:

```
SELECT keyword_search_table.nid, keyword_search_table.keyword, node_revisions.title, node_revisions.teaser, url_alias.pid FROM keyword_search_table INNER JOIN ON keyword_search_table.nid = node_revisions.nid INNER JOIN ON url_alias.pid = node_revisions.nid;
```

Comment: THis makes total sense to me. Thanks Ran! But one thing I know is that the keyword_search_table ID column has no relation to PID or NID. It is on its own.  each record in that table has a URL_Alias that matches a URL Alias in the url_alias table.

Comment: if keyword_search_table.id is not nid, you have  to find other linked data - ie, URL_Alias. The query should look like that

SELECT keyword_search_table.nid, keyword_search_table.keyword, node_revisions.title, node_revisions.teaser, url_alias.pid INNER JOIN ON keyword_search_table.url_alias = url_alias.url_alias INNER JOIN ON url_alias.pid = node_revisions.nid;

Comment: I don't want to sound dumb, but do I need a FROM someplace?

Comment: I am the dumb here, I forgot, I just edited the queries to include FROM

Comment: Ran! Thanks so much!I was able to get the data that I needed. I guess I had some confusion on the inner join.